# How can I make the sum of two elements in in different list?

Tags: python, list

I have 2 lists:

```
cat = [14.0, 13.0] and dog = [0.56, 0.98]
```

I need them to get the total I get I have to add them together.

but the answer I get when I do this is 13.256048520000002. How can I make it add all the elements? By the way, for this example, there is 2 elements per list but sometimes it could be 4, 5, 6,..

Comment: “I have to add 14.56 and 13.98 together to get my final result 70.0”… you lost me. 14.56 + 13.98 = 28.54

Comment: You're overwriting `result` each time through the loop, you're not accumulating a total.

Comment: `sum(cats) + sum(dogs)`??

Comment: Your code is doing a cross-product, adding each element of one list to every element of the other list. But your description says you just want to add corresponding elements, not every element. Use `zip()` to iterate in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

To get the element-wise sum you need to use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
cat = [14.0, 13.0]
dog = [0.56, 0.98]

[sum(x) for x in zip(cat, dog)]
```

Output:

```
[14.56, 13.98]
```

So `sum(sum(x) for x in zip(cat, dog))` should give you the grand total: `28.54`.

However, addition is [associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property), thus the order of the operations doesn't matter and you can simplify to:

```
sum(cat)+sum(dog)
```

Comment: @knsfcs then go with `zip` ;) ensure the lists are of equal length else use `itertool.zip_longest`

Comment: To break down the operation with `zip`: `[c+d for c,d in zip(cat, dog)]`

Answer (score 1):

`result=(a+b)` overwrites your `result` value every time.

You can visualize this with a simple print:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def get_total(cat, dog):
    for a in cat:
        for b in dog:
            result = (a+b)
            print(f"Result is now {result}")

    print(f"Final result: {result}")
    return result


cat = [14.0, 13.0]
dog = [0.56, 0.98]

print("Total: " + str(get_total(cat, dog)))
```

```
Result is now 14.56
Result is now 14.98
Result is now 13.56
Result is now 13.98
Final result: 13.98
Total: 13.98
```

If you want the total sum of all of them, you need something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def get_total(cat, dog):
    cat_total = 0
    for a in cat:
        cat_total += a

    dog_total = 0
    for b in dog:
        dog_total += b

    return cat_total + dog_total


cat = [14.0, 13.0]
dog = [0.56, 0.98]

print("Total: " + str(get_total(cat, dog)))
```

```
Total: 28.54
```

Although I'm still confused where you get `70.0`.